# How to change ls_colors

Tags: linux, cygwin

Hey i am trying to change the colors cygwin displays when i type ls --color for xml files.
I have tried adding the following in my .bashrc file but nothing seems to work

```
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS'xml=00;31'
export LS_COLORS
```

Would be greatly appreciated if someone could tell me which files to edit

Answer (score 2):

This is a question from 2014, but I've just been through the pain so I thought I'd give my tuppen'orth.

1) The default value of `LS_COLORS` already ends in a colon, so your setting would be fine:-

```
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS'xml=00;31'
```

But if the final colon was missing for some reason then you would need to add it:-

```
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS':xml=00;31'
```

or even:-

```
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS':xml=00;31:'
```

2) Make sure, when running `ls`, that you are actually using the `LS_COLORS` you have so carefully set:-

```
alias ls='ls --color'
```

3) Watch out for the utility `dircolors` overwriting your `LS_COLORS` with its **hardcoded** defaults. I couldn't work out what was overwriting my `LS_COLORS` until  I found this in my Ubuntu-default `.bashrc`:-

```
eval "$(dircolors)"
```

4) If you completely construct your own `LS_COLORS` and miss a setting, e.g. `ow`, then one of those same hardcoded defaults found in `dircolors` will be used, `:ow=34;42:` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

From the `man ls` page: "The environment variable `LS_COLORS` can influence the colors, and can be set easily by the `dircolors` command."

Assuming that you get the correct color syntax into your `LS_COLORS` environment variable, remember that it needs to be `export`ed and if you haven't done so, log out and log back in (or source your `.bashrc` using the command `. ~/.bashrc`).  Also, check the spelling of `.bashrc` compared with `.bashsrc`.

If all else fails, type the `LS_COLORS` commands you want directly into a running `bash` shell, to verify that your colors have the desired effect.  Then you know whether to change the commands, or to look at where they are interpreted.